# Javascript using regex throwing error

Tags: regex

**regex-javascript**
This code not working. when i click the search  button, its not showing anything. I need the following code to highlight first letter of the word.

```js
var str1 = document.getElementById("test").innerHTML;
function startswithSearch() {
    var str = str1;
    var input = document.getElementById("query").value;
    if (input) {                                              
        var pattern = new RegExp("^(" + input + ")", "gim");
        str = str.replace(pattern, "<span>$1</span>");
        document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = str;
    }
}
```

```css
span{
 background:yellow;
 font-weight:600;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="" method="" id="search" name="search">
<input name="query" id="query" type="text" size="30" maxlength="30">

<input name="startswith" type="button" value="startswith" onClick="startswithSearch()">

</form></div>
<div id="test">
<ul>
  <li>abcd</li>
  <li>efgh</li>

</ul>

</div>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="highlight_ts.js"></script>




</html>
```

It's throwing error and not working when i click the search button

> Not working...

Comment: What is  the error you're getting in Console?

Comment: no error in console, but can't get desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following script it should work . assuming you want span for the `<li>` elements

```
<script>
var str1 = document.getElementById("test").innerHTML;
function startswithSearch() {
    var str = str1;

    var input = document.getElementById("query").value;

    if (input) {                                              
        var pattern = new RegExp("(<li>\s*)("+input+")(.*?<\/li>)", "gim");
        console.log(pattern);
        str = str.replace(pattern, "$1<span>$2</span>$3");
        console.log(str);
        document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = str;
    }
}
</script>
```

EDIT:

Updated the script to highlight the search term alone. since your function is **`startswith`** I'm assuming the following

- Search term should be present at the start of `<li>` element.
- Spaces between `<li>` and its text are not considered

Comment: Awesome one !! but  when i enter "j" it highlights all words with "j". what i need is it should highlight only j.